# Newbie Seeking Assistance with Gravity Simulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to both JavaScript and programming in general, and I'm excited to dive into a gravity simulation project. However, I've encountered some issues with my code, and I'm looking for guidance and support from the experienced developers here.

I'm attempting to create a basic gravity simulation in JavaScript using HTML5 canvas. The goal is to simulate the gravitational attraction between two objects and observe their movements on the canvas.

The objects are not moving as expected.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// maximum and minimum mass for the bodies//
const max_mass = 10000;
const min_mass = 100;

// planets class//
class Planets {
  constructor(x, y, mass, radius) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.mass = mass;
    if (mass > max_mass) {
      this.mass = max_mass;
    }
    if (mass < min_mass) {
      this.mass = min_mass;
    }
    this.velocity = { x: 0, y: 0 }; 
    this.color = colours[random_index];
  }

  calculate_gravitational_force(body2, G = 6.6743e-11) {
    const dx = this.x - body2.x;
    const dy = this.y - body2.y;
    const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    const force_magnitude = (G * this.mass * body2.mass) / (distance * distance);
    const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    const force_x = force_magnitude * Math.cos(angle);
    const force_y = force_magnitude * Math.sin(angle);
    return { force_x, force_y };
  }

  update_position(forces, deltaTime) {
    const total_forces = forces.reduce(
      (acc, force) => ({
        force_x: acc.force_x + force.force_x,
        force_y: acc.force_y + force.force_y,
      }),
      { force_x: 0, force_y: 0 }
    );
    const acceleration_x = total_forces.force_x / this.mass;
    const acceleration_y = total_forces.force_y / this.mass;
    this.velocity.x += acceleration_x * deltaTime;
    this.velocity.y += acceleration_y * deltaTime;
    this.x += this.velocity.x * deltaTime;
    this.y += this.velocity.y * deltaTime;
  }
}

// star class//
class Star {
    constructor(x, y, mass, radius) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.mass = mass;
      this.velocity = { x: 0, y: 0 };
      this.radius = radius;
      this.color = "orange";
    }
  
    calculate_gravitational_force(body2, G = 6.6743e-11) {
      const dx = this.x - body2.x;
      const dy = this.y - body2.y;
      const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      const force_magnitude = (G * this.mass * body2.mass) / (distance * distance);
      const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      const force_x = force_magnitude * Math.cos(angle);
      const force_y = force_magnitude * Math.sin(angle);
      return { force_x, force_y };
    }
  
    update_position(forces, deltaTime) {
      const total_forces = forces.reduce(
        (acc, force) => ({
          force_x: acc.force_x + force.force_x,
          force_y: acc.force_y + force.force_y,
        }),
        { force_x: 0, force_y: 0 }
      );
      const acceleration_x = total_forces.force_x / this.mass;
      const acceleration_y = total_forces.force_y / this.mass;
      this.velocity.x += acceleration_x * deltaTime;
      this.velocity.y += acceleration_y * deltaTime;
      this.x += this.velocity.x * deltaTime;
      this.y += this.velocity.y * deltaTime;
    }
  }
  
// Random index for colours of planets//
var colours = ["red", "yellow", "green", "purple", "blue"];
const random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
let color_picked = colours[random_index];


// Create celestial body instances
const planet = new Planets(450, 300, 120, 20);
const myStar = new Star(755, 330, 1200, 100);

// Draw function for celestial bodies
function draw(object) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, object.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = object.color;
  ctx.fill();
}

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Calculate gravitational forces
  const force_between_bodies = [
    planet.calculate_gravitational_force(myStar),
    myStar.calculate_gravitational_force(planet),
  ];

  // Update positions based on forces
  planet.update_position(force_between_bodies, 1);
  myStar.update_position(force_between_bodies, 1);

  // Draw the celestial bodies
  draw(planet);

draw(myStar);

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. Please correct it to look like you expected since you messed up the pasting.